# How to improve the parallelization of the following piece of code?

Tags: programming, parallelization

I'm new to the parallelization of code. I have a code that takes so much time to run and I'm trying to parallelize it. I'm copying below the piece that I need to improve. Can someone help with the parallelization syntax?

````
ListParentCond = {ConditionX11, ConditionX13, ConditionX16, 
   ConditionX21, ConditionX22, ConditionX23, ConditionX31, 
   ConditionX73, ConditionX81, ConditionX91};

ListParentProfit = {Πr1X11, Πr1X13, \
Πr1X16, Πr1X21, Πr1X22, \
Πr1X23, Πr1X31, Πr1X73, \
Πr1X81, Πr1X91};

ListChildCond = {ConditionX1111, ConditionX1112, ConditionX1113};

ListChildProfit = {Πr1X1111, Πr1X1112, \
Πr1X1113};

CondF[i_, j_] := 
 CondF[i, j] = 
  Reduce[Exists[pn1, 
    ListChildCond[[j]] && ListParentCond[[i]] && 
     ListChildProfit[[j]] < ListParentProfit[[i]]], Reals]

Parallelize[Table[CondF[i, 1], {i, 1, 10}]] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelTable[CondF[i, 1], {i, 1, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
Table[CondF[i, 1], {i, 1, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
```
````

Comment: `Parallelize[Table[...]]` and `ParallelTable` should be equivalent. Please include the timing results.

Comment: They are almost equivalent but not too much gain as compared to Table. What Need is :

```
ParallelTable[CondF[i, j], {i, 1, 10},{j,1,100}]
```
Any tips that should make it faster?